# Rule to compare numeric values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have this rule "gt:registration_type_minimum" so that the user needs to enter a value in the field "registration_type_maximum" greater than the value introduced in the field "registration_type_minimum".

But the message is not appearing if is introduced in the registration_type_minimum field the value "2" and in the registration_type_maximum field the value "1".

```
$rules = [
  ...
    'registration_type_minimum' => 'nullable|integer|min:0',
    'registration_type_maximum' => 'nullable|gt:registration_type_minimum|integer|min:0',
];

$customMessages = [

  ....
    'registration_type_maximum.after_or_equal' => 'The maximum registrations per request needs to be greater then the minimum.',
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

In the request it appears:

```
 "registration_type_minimum" => "2"
  "registration_type_maximum" => "1"
```

But it shows: Method [validateGt] does not exist.

Comment: Did you define the custom rule for `gt`? Your error message suggests you didn't...

Comment: But there isnt a validation rule with name gt, like "gt:field"?

Comment: There is in Laravel 5.6 plus. What version are you using? Compare https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#available-validation-rules / https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: Its the 5.5 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules `gt`, `gte`, etc. were introduced in Laravel 5.6, and aren't available in Laravel 5.5. To use this rule, either upgrade to Laravel 5.6, or find the function definition in the codebase for Laravel 5.6 and extend your validator to use a copy.

For reference, the code can be found here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php

And how to extend the validator:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules